# The belongs to association makes ActiveRecord validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails `5.0.0.1`. Code snippet below is the model,

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notes
end
```

When I try to create a note in Rails console,

```
Note.create!(content: '1234')
```

It will produce the following error,

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Language must exist
```

Comment: what are the validations you have taken?

Comment: I do not have any validation inside my model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default

**In Rails 4**

`required` for `belongs_to` association is `false` by default in Rails 4.

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language, required: false
end
```

**In Rails 5**

To make its behavior like in Rails 4,

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language, optional: true
end
```

In Rails 5, `required` option for `belongs_to` is deprecated in favor of `optional`. (See Rails [Github PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937) "Require `belongs_to` by default")

**Make `optional:true` Across Entire App**

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```

You can also read ["Rails 5 makes `belongs_to` association required by default"](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) for more detail.